# random forest regression with uncertainty output

Tags: python, random-forest, uncertainty, bayesian-optimization

For a Bayesian optimization problem, I wish to use a random forest regressor in Python, able to predict for unseen data a probability distribution, like in the paper [Decision Forests for Classification,Regression, Density Estimation, ManifoldLearning and Semi-Supervised Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/decisionForests_MSR_TR_2011_114.pdf),
figure 4.3 page 55 for example.

Scikit-learn proposes a random forest regressor but the output is a predicted value with no uncertainty measure. Do you know any packages in Python implementing a random forest regressor able to predict a value for unseen data as well as some uncertainty over it (in the form of a probability distribution, or confidence interval) ?

Answer (score 1):

Per reference you supplied (which, by the way, I recommend as good reading), the comparison between Least-Squares regression and Forest regression is particularly interesting.  Per the presented example,  for one of the more simpler cases (at lower dimensionality), it appears that near the centroid (the point X-bar, Y- Bar), both Least-Squares and Forest regression are surprisingly close in their prediction/confidence intervals.  However, at points removed from the training sample (and the centroid), the confidence intervals correctly becomes larger, and in the case of Least-Squares, surprisingly larger.

As such, I would recommend applying Least-Squares regression model based prediction intervals as an approximation for the Forest regression model precision (uncertainty) estimates, at least for lower orders of dimensionality.

Comment: thank you for your answer. In this context, are what you call centroids the conditionnal means (green curve of fig 4.6 page 55) ?